# Convert index Match formula to VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, match

I have an array formula that I use on for approx. 600 rows to find the first -ve in each row, however it has slowed sheet up significantly.

Is there a way I can convert to a VBA function to help speed the sheet up?

```
=MATCH((INDEX(AN17:OI17,MATCH(TRUE,AN17:OI17<0,0))),AN17:OI17,0)
```

Richard

Comment: maybe you could provide an explanation as to how you're using it. It seems to be an array formula that is entered into all target cells at once.

Comment: Try this simplified, non-array formula: `=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(AN17:OI17<0,),0)`.  I tested it on 1000 rows and it seems to work with no slowdown on my system.

Comment: yeah, that seemed to be an awful lot of calculation to find the column index of the first negative number in a row.

Comment: As far as I know, VBA is slower than a formula, so instead of replacing your formula by a VBA function, you might try to work on the formula itself.

Answer (score 0):

Also, after running the macro, you cannot undo any action. This caused me a major headache in the past. I would suggest a formula.